# Multithreaded GUI window update in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface

I will start with the assumption that GUI event loop has to run in the main thread in Python. That's what I'm finding reading documentation of various GUI APIs. How can I render an image from a callback in another (not main) thread into the window controlled by the main thread? If it's possible, which GUI/visualization libraries in Python support this? All of them?

Comment: None of the UI frameworks allow you to touch the UI from other threads.  This is an operating system limitation, not a Python limitation.  Everything is done by messages, and messages are processed by the main loop, which is in the main thread.  All of the frameworks have a way for you to call a function in main thread.  Which UI are you using?

Comment: @TimRoberts I haven't decided yet, which one to use. Never did UI in Python before. Are you saying that I can call main thread UI function from callback thread and pass the image to be rendered?

Comment: Yes,  For example, wxPython has a `callAfter` function to which you can pass a callable and parameters, and the framework will call that function in the main thread, designed specifically for cases like this.  There is no locking in the UI libraries -- if you remember that, then the reasons become clear.